# integral over proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $S$ be a sub ring of a commutative ring $R$ let $y$ be in $R$. Prove that if $y$ is integral over $S$, then $S[y]$ is integral over $S$. I'm puzzled as how to start this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the following Lemma, which can be proved using the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem:

An element $x \in R$ is integral over $S$, if and only if there is a faithful $S[x]$-module which is finitely generated as $S$-module.

(We say that an $A$-module $M$ is faithful, if for every $0 \neq a \in A$ there is an $z \in M$ such that $a \cdot z \neq 0$)

Comment: No need to require faithfulness, me thinks.

Comment: Yes, we need faithfulness. Consider the polynomial ring $\mathbb{Z}[t]$. Clearly, $t$ is not integral over $\mathbb{Z}$, but we can equip $\mathbb{Z}$ with the following (non-faithful) $\mathbb{Z}[t]$-module structure: $p\cdot m := p(0) \cdot m$ for all $m\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $p \in \mathbb{Z}[t]$.

Comment: you're right. I was thinking of something else at all...